# Incorporating promising chaining into navigation for an AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created an AngularJS application that has dialog instances which allow the user to navigate. I'm in need of a queue to properly handle the saving of data and presentation of data. So far the navigation I've created is located inside of a controller which is also saving and retrieve the section information.

My question is that should I remove the navigation from the controller and create a service that incorporates promise chaining or should I leave the navigation in the controller?

Comment: It's not clear without code. You can try to implement the save functionality in both ways, then ask for our opinions.

Comment: The controllers purpose is to work as the connecting piece between logic and view. You should try to keep them as slim as possible. personally, i mostly use controllers to define actions on the view and call corresponding service methods.